# How to add 'AND' tag exclusion in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create filtered browsing of movie titles. A user could search for all movies that have romance,drama genres/tags in them but they must NOT have comedy in them.

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `genres_in_movies` (
  `genre_id` int NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`genre_id`) REFERENCES `genres`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies`(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO genres(gname) VALUES('Comedy'),('Horror'),('Drama'),('Suspense'),('Romance'),('Documentary');

INSERT INTO movies(title) VALUES("Zoolander"),("Inception"),("Jurassic");

insert into genres_in_movies(genre_id,movie_id) values 
(1,1),(3,1),(5,1),
(2,2),(4,2),
(6,2),
(1,3),(2,3),(3,3);
```

What i've done in the following [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f97bb/111) has the inclusion part working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.title, gim.genres
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genres_in_movies ON movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT movie_id, group_concat(genres.gname) as genres
  FROM genres_in_movies
  INNER JOIN genres ON genre_id = genres.id
  GROUP by movie_id
) AS gim ON gim.movie_id = m.id
WHERE genres_in_movies.genre_id IN (5)
AND genres_in_movies.genre_id not in(1)
```

However, the inclusion works by using OR and if i just add a NOT IN clause for the exclusion it wont work since the exclusion needs to use AND.

The only solution i found to this is in mssql by using temporary tables and copying data, which is as you might know horribly slow. I've found numerous solutions here but none do what i need.

The fiddle has my database structure and the current progress.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to use the latin1 charset

Comment: Why? I need a charset that can support japanese/chinese

Comment: So how's Latin1 going to help you with that?

Comment: Its not, which one should i use? UTF?

Comment: Yes, UTF8(mb4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.title, GROUP_CONCAT(g.gname) genres
FROM movies m
JOIN genres g
JOIN genres_in_movies gm ON m.id = gm.movie_id AND g.id = gm.genre_id
GROUP BY m.title
HAVING SUM(g.gname = 'Romance')      -- must be present
   AND NOT SUM(g.gname = 'Comedy')   -- must be absent
/* AND SUM(g.gname IN ('Romance', 'Comedy'))     -- must present at least one of */
/* AND NOT SUM(g.gname IN ('Romance', 'Comedy')) -- must absent all of           */
```

Comment: Very interesting use of `SUM()`! Never read a use like this before. I vote for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
SELECT movie_id, title, group_concat(genres.gname) as genres
  FROM genres_in_movies
  INNER JOIN genres ON genre_id = genres.id
  INNER JOIN movies ON genres_in_movies.movie_id=movies.id
  GROUP by movie_id
  HAVING FIND_IN_SET('Romance',genres) 
    AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('Comedy',genres);
```

Because you're using `GROUP_CONCAT`, you can add a [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function at the end with `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Hm, this doesnt work with multiple tags. I just used 'Comedy,Drama' however no results are found. Does this compare strings because of the group_concat?

Comment: Unfortunately `FIND_IN_SET` only find substrings separated by comma (,).. to omit 'Comedy' and 'Drama' from the result, you need to add another `AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('Drama',genres)` after `NOT FIND_IN_SET('Comedy',genres)`.

Answer (score 0):

Is adding a simple `AND NOT EXISTS` with a subquery helping you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.title, gim.genres
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genres_in_movies AS inclusionGenres ON inclusionGenres.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT movie_id, group_concat(genres.gname) as genres
  FROM genres_in_movies
  INNER JOIN genres ON genre_id = genres.id
  GROUP by movie_id
) AS gim ON gim.movie_id = m.id
WHERE inclusionGenres.genre_id IN (5)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM genres_in_movies AS exlusionGenres WHERE exlusionGenres.movie_id = m.id AND exlusionGenres.genre_id in(1))
```

I think its also possible with a JOIN on 'exclusionGenres'.

**Edit, add a join example:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.id, m.title, gim.genres
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN genres_in_movies AS inclusionGenres ON inclusionGenres.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT movie_id, group_concat(genres.gname) as genres
  FROM genres_in_movies
  INNER JOIN genres ON genre_id = genres.id
  GROUP by movie_id
) AS gim ON gim.movie_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN genres_in_movies AS exlusionGenres ON (exlusionGenres.movie_id = m.id AND exlusionGenres.genre_id in(3))
WHERE inclusionGenres.genre_id IN (5)
AND exlusionGenres.genre_id IS NULL;
```